# Simulink: Identifying a block from an online source - w in a box

Tags: matlab, simulink

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10WHr.jpg) you find the screenshot of the exact thing I mean. I've already figured out the rest so don't mind it. The w in a box blocks are the ones still puzzling me.

---

Solved: A person on reddit helped me solve this. I'm going to quote his answer below.

> The middle red circle isn't a built-in simulink block. it's probably a subsystem just for sensing. The "ssc_dcmotor" demo model uses the same subsystem. In that demo model, all the "w" subsystem contains is an "Ideal Rotational Motion Sensor" block and a "PS-Simulink Converter" block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's the [PS-Simulink Converter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/pssimulinkconverter.html) block.